# Having a couple of issues with session storage and if statement to store name in a separate file

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

I am having trouble with displaying stored name using "Session Storage" in an separate html file. I want it to be executed when I click "enter" button so that "name" section changes into a name that users typed. To further explain what should be happening.

1. When the users type nothing = "", it should prevent the user from moving forward and the "What is your name" part changed into "Please enter your name".
2. When the users type a word or their names, the stored name is to be displayed in  inside home.html page.

```js
// login.js section

var username = document.getElementById("user_name");
var enter = document.getElementById("enter");
var firstname = document.getElementById("name");
var message = document.getElementById("message");

function login(){
    if (username.value == "") {
     message.innerHTML = "Please enter your name.";
    } else {
        enter.addEventListener("click",function(){
            window.location.href = "home.html";
            sessionStorage.setItem('name',username.value);
            firstname.innerText = sessionStorage.getItem('name');
            console.log(name);
        });
    }   
}
```

```html
          <!-- This is located in login.html -->
          <div id="question" class="question_ani">
                <h1 id="message">What is your name?</h1>
            </div>

            <input type="text" id="user_name" maxlength="10" class="input_ani">

         <button id="enter" class="animate-bottom" type="button" onclick="login()">enter</button>
         
          <hr>
          <!-- This is located in home.html -->
          <div class="speech" id="speech">Hi, <span id="name">name</span><br />Weclome to Recyclone.<br />I am here to teach you how to recycle in a fun way. <br />Let's learn how to recycle!</div>
          
         <!-- both are linked to <script src=js/login.js></script> -->
```

***Problems I am having.***

1. The session storage is working as well as message changing part, but for some reason, users have to click the "enter" button **twice** to move forward.
2. Like aforementioned, the stored name should be displayed in the  section but it is not displaying it for some reason.*

I am always grateful for constant community help and thank you in advance to those who take time to read it through. Here is my github link for this project for details. https://github.com/monuda85/recyclone

Comment: Have you tried to call the `window.location.href` at the end of that block?, Also you need to attach the `enter` click event before, here you are attaching the event if the username.value is not empty

Comment: Thanks, those were the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are creating an event listener inside the event handler for the login button, so when you click the button the first time you're telling it what to do when it's clicked, but you then have to click it again to make it happen.

As for the second problem, in order to see the value you'll need to get it from `sessionStorage` on `home.html` and show it there.  You set the value and then immediately move to another page which is why you don't see it.

Ideally, remove `onclick="login()"` from the button and change your code to this...

```
enter.addEventListener("click", login); // assign the click handler like this

function login() {
    if (username.value == "") {
        message.innerHTML = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    else {
        sessionStorage.setItem("name", username.value);

        // you won't see the effects of these 2 lines for long (if at all)
        // because you immediately go to another page.
        firstname.innerText = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
        console.log(name);

        window.location.href = "home.html";
    }   
}
```

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)